# NSPopUpButton: events from menu tracking?

Tags: cocoa, nspopupbutton

Is it possible to detect actions that tell my controller when the user is mousing (or otherwise perusing) the items in an NSPopUpButton?  I only seem to be notified on a new selection and I'd like to be notified as the user is rolling over any item in the menu.

thanks

tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your controller as the delegate of the `NSPopUpButton`'s menu. You will then be sent `-menu:willHighlightItem:` delegate messages as the mouse tracks over the menu.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[popupButton menu] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)menu:(NSMenu *)menu willHighlightItem:(NSMenuItem *)item
{
    if(menu == [popupButton menu])
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be better to just test whether they're the same menu (`menu == [popUpButton menu]`). Assuming NSMenu implements a deeper meaning of `isEqual:`, do you really want to perform the action when the user highlights items in an unrelated menu that happens to have “the same” (for some definition of *that*) menu items?

Comment: That's a fair point. I've amended the code to use a straight pointer comparison.

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks very much for taking the time to answer.  I'll give this a shot!!